# return one string with multiple column value linq

Tags: c#, linq

I have a query.

Is it possible to return One string with multiple column value in linq ??

Like this

```
string ProductName = ((from P in DataModel.DIS_PRODUCT
                       join M in DataModel.SET_PACK_UNIT on P.PUNIT_ID equals M.ID
                       where P.PRODUCT_ID == ProdictId
                       select P.PRODUCT_NAME +" " + P.WEIGHT + " "+ M.UNIT_SYMBLE)
                       .Take(1)
                     ).ToString();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using `Take(1)` which means you're still getting an `IEnumerable<string>` or an `IQueryable<string>`. Just use `First()` (or possibly `FirstOrDefault()`) instead of `Take(1)` and you can drop the `ToString()` call as well.

```
string productName = (from P in DataModel.DIS_PRODUCT
                      join M in DataModel.SET_PACK_UNIT
                        on P.PUNIT_ID equals M.ID
                      where P.PRODUCT_ID == ProdictId
                      select P.PRODUCT_NAME + " " + P.WEIGHT + " "+ M.UNIT_SYMBLE)
                     .FirstOrDefault();
```

That will only work if your LINQ provider supports the string concatenation operation. An alternative is to fetch just the columns you want, and then concatenate at the caller:

```
var query = from P in DataModel.DIS_PRODUCT
            join M in DataModel.SET_PACK_UNIT
              on P.PUNIT_ID equals M.ID
            where P.PRODUCT_ID == ProdictId
            select new { P.PRODUCT_NAME, P.WEIGHT, M.UNIT_SYMBLE };

var result = query.FirstOrDefault();
if (result != null)
{
    string productName = result.PRODUCT_NAME + " " +
                         result.WEIGHT + " " +
                         result.UNIT_SYMBLE;
    // Use the name
}
else
{
    // No results
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Another more clear way is the following

```
var ProductsQueryItem = (from p in Products
              select new
              {
                  Name = e.ProductName+ " " + e.weight +e.UNIT_SYMBLE
              })
.FirstOrDefault();
```

Now you can use it directly with ProductsQueryItem .Name